# how to run jquery ajax in cronjob

Tags: cron, jquery-ajaxq

i want to run a ajax function in cronjob..

my code is :

```
<?php
function sendSMS($username, $password, $phones, $text){?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function (){ 

  var smsUrl='http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username=<?php echo $username ?>&password=<?php echo $password ?>&sendername=NETSMS&mobileno=<?php echo $phones ?>&message=<?php echo $text?>'; 

    $.ajax({

                 data     : '',
                 type     : "get",
                 url      : smsUrl,
                 error    : function(resp){
                 },
                 success  : function(resp){
                 }

   });
});
</script>
<?php }?>
```

the code is working fine if i run the php page manually in the browser.. but not work in cron job... is it possible to run ajax function in cronjob?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to my attention (or just very difficult and not user-friendly).

You can acquire the same thing using CURL. 
Make your cron job run a script that contacts bulksms.mysms... through CURL.
I dont know if your server runs asp or php or whatever.

Example:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$remote_url = 'http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username=' . $username . '&password=' . $password . '&sendername=NETSMS&mobileno=' .  $phones . '&message=' . $text;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $remote_url);     

// Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

// Return output
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Are you sure you installed curl library for php on your server?

Comment: m using php.. i have tried curl function but its not working

Comment: I updated the answer so you can see an example. If curl doesnt work, then why doesnt it work? What's the error message?